# Which model to choose based on Precision and Recall values for imbalanced classes

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall, imbalanced-data

I am working on wine quality dataset for predicting if the quality of wine is good or bad.

I have used multiple classification models and calculated their accuracy/Precision/Recall score as shown below

[image: Accuracy\Precision\Recall]

However , I can not rely on accuracy score as data is imbalance i.e. Data with class **Bad**(1382 rows) is greater then class **Good**

Which model should I prefer based on above precision and recall score and why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: That said, the appropriate metric is normally dictated by the *business* problem we are trying to solve.

Comment: You may find [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score) useful, it is harmonic mean of precision and recall.